# JavaScript - jQuery interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am using JavaScript with jQuery. I have the following script to alert `hi` every 30 seconds.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    alert("hi");
setInterval(function() {
    alert("hi");
}, 30000);
});
```

I want to alert `hi` when the page loads (when document / page gets completely loaded) and on every 30 seconds interval afterwards (like `hi`(0s) - `hi`(30s) - `hi`(60s).. etc). But my solution works on two instances. One on DOM ready and the other in a loop. Is there any way to do the same in a single instance?

You can see my fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/blasteralfred/kejJC/)**.

Comment: What is the problem?  Your jsFiddle alerts initially and every 30 seconds thereafter exactly as the code specifies.  setInterval does not call it's function until the time elapses.  If you want it executed initially, then you just call it as you did.  If it's a more complicated piece of logic you want called in both places, then just put it in a named function that you can call both places.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use setTimeout instead and have the callback reschedule itself.

```
$(function() {
    sayHi();

    function sayHi() {
       setTimeout(sayHi,30000);
       alert('hi');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just use setInterval?

Comment: @user2019515 - I understood the OP wanted a single invocation of the function. `$(function() { sayHi(); setInterval(sayHi,30000); function sayHi() { alert('hi');});` would also work but has separate instances of the function.

Comment: Question is related to setinterval function they why are you suggesting about settimeout function.

Answer (score 12):

Wrap your code in a function. Then, pass the function as a first argument to `setInterval`, and call the function:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    //Definition of the function (non-global, because of the previous line)
    function hi(){
        alert("hi");
    }

    //set an interval
    setInterval(hi, 30000);

    //Call the function
    hi();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, there probably is a way of doing it in just one call..

```
setInterval(
    (function x() {
        alert('hi');
        return x;
    })(), 30000);
```

Another solution would be to use arguments.callee, but as it is now deprecated, it is generally not recommended to use it.

```
setInterval(
    (function() {
        alert('hi');
        return arguments.callee;
    })(), 30000);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible with `setInterval`. You could use setTimeout for example:

```
function foo() {
    alert('hi');
    setTimeout(foo, 30000);
}

$(function() {
    foo();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {

    function heythere() {
        alert('hi');
        setTimeout(heythere,30000);
    }

    heythere();

});
```

If you want it to only run once after 30 seconds, you are looking to use `setTimeout` not `setInterval`.