# Timer/Interval on HTML5/jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am looking to create a HTML5/jQuery like pop-out/throbbing/pulsing effect on images.

I have a HTML5 example of an image popout, right now this only works on Hoverover.

I am using standards CSS3 and HTML5 to create an enlarging effect on an image.

The effect looks like this: http://codecanyon.net/theme_previews/1318001-killer-css3-image-hover-effects?index=1

I want to do this on page load, automatically, every 5 seconds.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546565/javascript-jquery-interval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using jQuery functions: `setInterval` or `setTimeout`.