# Auto updating Image using mysql php and i would assume javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, dynamic

Alright, So I've searched google for what i'm trying to do and can't seem to find what i am exactly looking for.

What I would like to do is have a image that is updated every second, this image is used for a message icon, similar to that of Facebook. No page refresh, Need the element updated using Jquery(preferred). I know very little on the java-script side of this, however the PHP and MySQL side I can do as long as i know what to tell the java-script to do.

I guess the real Question would be:
How can i make the image update based upon, any change in the MySQL database?
Any help on this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: welcome to the world of ajax my friend :) .. a few quick searches on google will help u find exactly what u need.

Comment: Every second? Expect high throughput bills. You might want to look into Comet, Meteor, socket.io... PHP is not very good at these things.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    $.get("url", { parameters: egTime}, function(response) {
        if($("#myImage").attr("src") != response)
            $("#myImage").attr("src", response);
    })
}, 1000);
```

the server has to return the new src of the image as a string ;-)

Comment: I would assume url would mean something like "ajaxscript.php" now would that file just have a raw output of whatever image path needs to be displayed? Or how would the response work?

Comment: The response is just the new URL of the IMG like:
"//myFolder/myimage.png"

Comment: Personally I would rather use json, echo json_encode(array('url' => $url)); then on the js side  $("#myImage").attr("src", response.url);

Answer (score 0):

You may first set an interval using jQuery. Refer this question;

[JavaScript - jQuery interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546565/javascript-jquery-interval)

Then you may do ajax requests on that intervals to check for new entries in database. In MySQL, make a flag entry to identify whether the entry is new or old (say set 0 for old and 1 for new). On each ajax request, if there is any entry with status 1, then the PHP may return that number of entries having 1 (ie, may be greater than 1) as the ajax result. Then the status should be set to 0. In javascript ajax, you may check whether the return value is 0 or else. If 0, then you need not do anything. If 1, then you may change some element's css property (like changing background color), so as to make it a notification. When user click that element, the css may be brought back to default.

Comment: The 1/0 is already done, it works fine for normal page loads, just need it to keep going so you dont have to refresh the page