# Make a interval in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I have this function, `$('.trigger-list li ').addClass('animate');`

I have a list with 5 list items. When i fire this code. Every second one list item must get the classe animate. How can i set a interval on this?

Thanks

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081443/run-a-function-in-time-interval-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: What exactly do you expect to happen every second?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - jQuery interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546565/javascript-jquery-interval)

Comment: Re-read your question, is it clear for you? So each second one and only one element must get class animate, other should have class removed, is it this or what? Couldn't you improve your question???

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.trigger-list li ').addClass('animate');
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using the jQuery `:odd` selector https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/

```
$('.trigger-list li:odd ').addClass('animate');
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? OP's question is ambiguous and this seems like a valid answer.

Comment: I actually didn't downvote this but why do you think this would be the solution? The requester did not specify every second row to be animated

Comment: Thats actually what I thought he was asking.

Comment: grammar makes all the difference 'Every second, one..' vs 'Every second one...'