# How do I make this code refresh every minute?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How do I make this code refresh every minute?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j(document).ready(function () { 
    $j('#left-box').load('pages/box.php'); 
});
</script>
```

I want it to refresh every 1 minute I've tried other stuff cant do it

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/timers#setInterval(callback.2C_ms))?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript - jQuery interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546565/javascript-jquery-interval)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setInterval` as follows:

```
$j(document).ready(function () { 
    setInterval(function () { $j('#left-box').load('pages/box.php') }, 60000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 setInterval(
     function(){
     $j('#left-box').load('pages/box.php'); 
 }, 
 60000)
```

60000 is a minute in miliseconds. That function you pass in will run once every 60000 miliseconds (every minute).