# How to display COUNT() result from mysql to a webpage and automatically update without refreshing webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table;
```

And I want to display it in my webpage and automatically update it without refreshing the webpage.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h5>/*mysql query result goes here*/</h5>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I also have this count.php:

```
<?php
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "root";
 $password = "root";
 $dbname = "myDB";

 $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }

  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM my_table";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
  echo $row['Count'];
  $conn->close();
?>
```

I don't know how to display the count in my html. I also want to update the display automatically without refreshing the webpage, lets say every 30 seconds.

Comment: Are these on the same file, or separate files?

Comment: You'll probably want to do an ajax call then. jQuery `$.ajax` that file.

Comment: I don't know how to do ajax call.

Comment: You need to learn; the question's too broad and holds too many possible answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do an ajax call to your `count.php`

```
$.ajax({
     url: "count.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){
         $("#result").html(html);
     }
 });
```

Your html file can now contain

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <h5 id="result">/*mysql query result goes here*/</h5>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

More information on `$.ajax`; http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: You'll want to add an `exit;` at the end of your `count.php` file

Comment: Where do I put that ajax call?

Comment: My apologies you'll want to add the `<script> /*ajax code*/ </script>` before the end of your `</body>` and add jQuery to your html head `<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` That's the CDN for v2

Comment: That's it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: To make it run periodically you can add the ajax code in a function `function getCount(){/*ajax call*/} check out this post; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546565/javascript-jquery-interval

Comment: Is this right? <script>setInterval(function(){$('#result').load('count.php');}, 30000)</script> It's working.

Answer (score 0):

you should use post() Methode form jquery with setTimeout().

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h5 id="count">/*mysql query result goes here*/</h5>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script>
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post("Count.php",
               {get_count:true},
                function(result){
                    $("#count").html(result);
                }
             );
        },30000);
    </script> 
</html>
```

Dont forget to Change the php file. You need to check if POST['get_count'] isst, if you want to handle More then one Post request.